# Selecting table records using Sinatra and ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, mariadb, unicorn

I am trying to query a MariaDB i have setup alongside Sinatra using ActiveRecords.

**My table schema is as follows**

```
MariaDB [orbital]> select * from posts
    -> ;
+----+------+------+----------+
| id | user | post | location |
+----+------+------+----------+
|  1 | 100  | 100  | 100      |
+----+------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Sinatra is setup with Unicorn and Nginx to proxy the requests.

**MyApp.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'
require 'table_print'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql2",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "root",
  :database => "orbital"
)

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
  get '/' do
    p Post.all
  end
end
```

I user Kurly to `kurly -X GET -k localhost

I get the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

I have tried modifying the ruby file but I get different results. Using `table_print` will allow the page to load by with 0 bytes. I am certain that I am using ActiveRecord wrongly or have setup something incorrectly and would appreciate a usable example to select data from my table.

Comment: Just a stupid question: if you turn into string `'Post.all'` does it print to browser?

Comment: ```Post.all``` doesn't seem to work but I managed to figure a way to print out the entries using ```Post.to_yaml```

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to catch that code into an exception and check the exception message to see if it throws something important with a simple `puts`. If that doesn't work, you can use a debugger to check the exact error and the cause of the error.

It may be some misconfiguration to the `establish_connection` method. Maybe the credentials are wrong or something.

A good debugger I use is `pry`, you can add it to your Gemfile, import the gem into your controller file and use `binding.pry` to enter in the debugger mode.